# Expression In ASP.Net Core 3.1 RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net-core, rdlc

My ASP.Net Core RDLC Report is working fine but tried to hide row when the field value is zero by right click the rdlc report row and then click Row Visibility. In the Row Visibility dialog box I selected Show Or Hide based on an Expression Under Change display options and used this expression

```
IIf(Fields!StudentAmt.Value=0,True,False)
```

and got the following error.

`ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘[BC30390] 'AspNetCore.ReportingServices.RdlExpressions.ExpressionHostObjectModel.DataRegionExprHost(Of TMemberType, TCellType).m_memberTreeHostsRemotable' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend`

I am using Reference of `AspNetCore.Reporting` for local Report

And this Second Error displayed as a result of this expression `Format(Fields!OEndDate.Value, "MMM-yyyy")`

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

My Controller

```
public IActionResult Report()
 {
   string mimtype = "";
   int extension = 1;
   Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
      { "rpl", “Student Name” }
   };
    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(mypath);
    localReport.AddDataSource("DataSet1", mydatasource);
    var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimtype);

   return File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf");
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `AspNetCore.Reporting`? Do not use any expressions, report will fail. This is limitation of this library.

If you wish to hide rows using the expression, I recommend you to use `ReportViewerCore.NETCore`.

Below is my test, you can refer to it:

```
public IActionResult Report()
{
    var test = _context.Table.ToList();
    var path = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report2.rdlc";

    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.ReportPath= path;
            
    report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", test));
    report.SetParameters(new[] { new ReportParameter( "rdl", "Student Name" ) });
    byte[] pdf = report.Render("PDF");
    return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
}
```

Before using the expression:

[image]

After using the expression:

[image]

Output Result:

[image]

More details about `ReportViewerCore.NETCore`, you can refer to [this link](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore).

Your second error may just be a problem with data loading, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f) to solve it.

Comment: Thanks Chen your suggestion is Ok. but I try to Install `ReportViewerCore.NETCore` did not install. I don't know the problem for not install. Using ASP.Net 3.1 Community Version 2019.

Comment: During the installation, are there any error messages in the "`Error List`"? @dausa

Comment: Try to install multiple times, pay attention to whether there is an error log output.

Comment: Here is an error `Could not install package 'ReportViewerCore.NETCore 15.1.17'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`.

Comment: Can you share your `.csproj` file? @dausa

Comment: For [.NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportViewerCore.NETCore) and  [.NET Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer) is different. Please confirm it.

Comment: Here is .csproj `<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
`

Comment: how to change TargetFramework and my project remain working